# Task.WhenAll Multithreading runs sequentially instead of parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, multitasking

I have an application in which I initially establish, in how many (Microsoft) teams I am the owner, out of all the teams I am member of.
So if I'm member of 37 teams, I need to end up with a list of the 13 teams I actually am owner of.

It works - querying MS Graph of owners foreach team - however some useres are owner of hundreds of teams, and it is obvious that the load time is unacceptable when having to wait for a sequential load.
So I'm trying to fix this with `Task.Select` and `Task.WhenAll`. However the tasks run sequentially and not parallel.
I'm quite interested in bringing the total loadtime down to the approx 250 ms, in stead of 250 times 37.
I have read that the `task.WhenAll` is rather offended if I use `.Result` in a task, leading it to run sequentially, but I cant figure out what to do to make this run in parallel threads.

```
 private static async Task DispatchGetTeamOwnersAsync(JEnumerable<JToken> userTeams, GraphittiBox.Model.TokenObject token)
        {

            var tasks = userTeams.Select(async team =>
            {
                Team t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Team>(team.ToString());
                Stopwatch clock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                LogService.WriteLog("await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync");

                
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.Token_type, token.Access_token);
                var url = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/owners?$select=mail,id,displayName".Replace("{groupId}", t.Id));
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url);

                var content = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject owners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content.Result);

                JsonOwnersCollection.Add(new OwnersAsyncList(t.Id, owners));


                clock.Stop();
                LogService.WriteLog("Done (" + clock.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms)");
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        }
```

Logfile:

```
05-03-2021 08:21:04 Info    User initiated 'ProcessForm'
05-03-2021 08:21:05 Info    User has a total of 37 UserJoinedTeams
05-03-2021 08:21:05 Info    Method: GetAsyncOwners (ProcessForm)
05-03-2021 08:21:05 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:06 Info    Done (335 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:06 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:06 Info    Done (237 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:06 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:06 Info    Done (231 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:06 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    Done (214 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    Done (219 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    Done (229 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    Done (217 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:07 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    Done (314 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    Done (225 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    Done (203 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    Done (206 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    Done (251 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:08 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:09 Info    Done (289 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:09 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:09 Info    Done (224 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:09 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:09 Info    Done (258 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:09 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    Done (240 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    Done (317 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    Done (297 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    Done (255 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:10 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:11 Info    Done (208 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:11 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:11 Info    Done (243 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:11 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:11 Info    Done (260 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:11 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    Done (369 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    Done (248 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    Done (232 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    Done (300 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:12 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    Done (233 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    Done (249 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    Done (253 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    Done (262 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:13 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    Done (243 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    Done (227 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    Done (235 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    Done (257 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:14 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:15 Info    Done (225 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:15 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:15 Info    Done (231 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:15 Info    await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync
05-03-2021 08:21:15 Info    Done (227 ms)
05-03-2021 08:21:15 Info    User is owner of 13 UserJoinedTeams
```

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` *waits* for already executing tasks, it doesn't run them. The code has several bugs - creating a new instance of `HttpClient` instead of reusing one instance is a serious bug. You don't notice it because the next bug, blocking the async calls with `.Result`, ensures only one `GetAsync()` or `ReadAsStringAsync` call can work at a time. You have a synchronous loop. The only reason it compiles is the (useless otherwise) `async` keyword

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
var content = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The `.Result` part will cause block until the task is complete. You should instead await the task.

Answer (score 2):

All this can be reduced to :

```
var ownerTasks=userTeams
       .Cast<JObject>()
       .Select(j=>{
           var id=j.GetValue("Id");
           return $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners?$select=mail,id,displayName";
        })
        .Select(async url=>await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
        .Select(json=>JObject.Parse(json));

var owners=await Task.WhenAll(ownerTasks);
```

If you used the Microsoft Graph SDK or an OData client you could avoid JObject altogether

---

`Task.WhenAll` doesn't execute tasks, it waits for them to complete.

There are several problems in this code

- Creating a new instance of HttpClient instead of reusing one instance is a serious bug that can lead to socket exhaustion
- The code is blocking the async calls with .Result. This ensures only one GetAsync() or ReadAsStringAsync call can work at a time.
- Adding the results to a global collection, `JsonOwnersCollection`. This needs locking or a concurrent collection. It's not needed though

The `Select` is synchronous and only returns `Task`s because of the (otherwise useless) `async` keyword. I'm sure the compiler generated a warning saying just that.

The code should look like this at least :

```
//Use one instance only. It's thread-safe and *meant* to be reused
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.Token_type, token.Access_token);

var ownerTasks = userTeams
    .Select(async team =>
    {
        //What's the point of this? 
        Team t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Team>(team.ToString());
        var clock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        LogService.WriteLog("await: GetOwnersOfTeamAsync");
        var url = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/owners?$select=mail,id,displayName".Replace("{groupId}", t.Id));

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var owners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content);
        LogService.WriteLog($"Done ({clock.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms)");

        return new OwnersAsyncList(t.Id, owners);         
    });

var owners=await Task.WhenAll(ownerTasks);
```

There other things that can change. These two lines :

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Can be replaced with

```
var content=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

The URL can be constructed in one step, avoiding temporary strings:

```
var url = new Uri($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{t.Id}/owners?$select=mail,id,displayName");
```

And instead of converting the `team` to a `string` only to deserialize it into a `Team` - why not pass a list of `Team` objects instead? Even if there's a reason to use `JSToken` there's no reason to serialize and parse this. A `JObject` *is* a `JToken`. The serialization/deserialization would fail if a `JArray` or `JProperty` was passed instead.

Getting the ID can be done with :

```
var id=((JObject)team).GetValue("Id");
```

All this becomes:

```
var ownerTasks=userTeams
       .Cast<JObject>()
       .Select(j=>{
           var id=j.GetValue("Id");
           return $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners?$select=mail,id,displayName";
        })
        .Select(async url=>await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
        .Select(json=>JObject.Parse(json));

var owners=await Task.WhenAll(ownerTasks);
```

Finally, the main problem with HTTP endpoints isn't how to make multiple concurrent calls. A simple `urls.Select(url=>httpClient.GetStringAsync(url))` is enough. It's how to *throttle* the calls, and execute only a few at a time.

An easy way to do this is to use the Dataflow classes to execute multiple concurrent operations with a restricted degree of parallelism.

```
var dop=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism=8 //Adjust based on Graph's throttling limits
};
var block=new TransformBlock<string,JObject>(async j=>{
     var id=j.GetValue("Id");
     var url= $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners?$select=mail,id,displayName";
     var json=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
      return JObject.Parse(json)
    })

var buffer=new BufferBlock<JObject>();

block.LinkTo(buffer)

foreach(var j in teams)
{
    block.Post(j);
}

block.Complete();
//Wait for all operations to complete
await block.Completion;
//The buffer contains all results now
```

Comment: Looks like you should do: `.Select(async json => JObject.Parse(await json));` as `json` is still a `task<string>` rather than `string`

Answer (score 1):

The use of `var` here hides the fact that your intermediates are `Task<T>` and not `T`. And `.Result` should be avoided, it blocks.

```
//var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url);
//var content = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
//JObject owners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content.Result);

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);  
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject owners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content);
```

Note that your original loop code does not have any `await`s, that's why your Tasks are synchronous and WhenAll runs them sequentially.